# Programa retorna sempre o mesmo resultado em C

Tags: c, while

O código roda normal mas só da uma saída: *domingo*! independente do numero escolhido.

### O que o programa deverá fazer

Implemente um programa que tenha como entrada um número (*1-7*) que corresponde a um dos dias da semana e imprima na tela o nome do dia correspondente (*domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado*).

Se o número lido não estiver no intervalo *1-7*, imprima: *Numero de dia não válido*.

O programa deve permanecer executando até que o usuário tecle o numero *0*. Utilize obrigatoriamente um teste no início.

### Código

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void){
    char ch;
    char domingo = '1',segunda = '2',terca = '3',quarta = '4', quinta = '5',sexta = '6',sabado = '7';
    printf("digite um numero que corresponde a um dia da semana: n");
    ch = getchar();
    while(ch!= 0){
        if (ch=1){
            printf(" domingo n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=2){
            printf(" segunda n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=3){
            printf(" terca  n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=4){
            printf(" quarta n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=5){
            printf(" quinta n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=6){
            printf(" sexta  n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=7){
            printf(" sabado n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch>7 && ch!=0){
            printf(" numero de dia nao valido n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `0` (`1` ...) e `'0'` (`'1'` ...) são diferentes

Comment: te aconselho a usar o switch case em vez desta quantidade de `ifs` e `elses` basta você fazer, case 1,case2 etc... e default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há três problemas no seu código:

1. Você está usando o operador de atribuição (`=`), e não o operador de comparação (`==`). A condição do `while` e o último `if` estão ok, pois você usa diferente (`!=`) e maior (`>`), os demais devem ser ajustados para usar esse operador.

   ```
   if ( ch == 1 ) {
   ```

   A propósito, quando você faz `if ( ch = 1 )` o que acontece é o seguinte: primeiro ele atribui `ch` para `1`; depois a expressão inteira avalia em `1`, e esse valor é que é usado como a condição do `if`. Como `1` é considerado "verdadeiro" (somente `0` é falso), então ele entra no `if` e imprime "Domingo".
2. Você está lendo caracteres (`char`) e comparando-os com números inteiros (`int`), e isso não só está incorreto nesse caso como vai falhar silenciosamente - sem mostrar nenhuma mensagem de erro - pois o C converte automaticamente `char` para `int` quando ambos são usados numa mesma operação.

   Um caractere lido do teclado vai vir codificado usando a codificação de caracteres (*encoding*) padrão do seu terminal. Provavelmente `Cp1252`, se for um sistema Windows em português, ou `UTF-8` (Unicode) se for um sistema Linux. Em ambos os casos, o código para os números de `0` a `7` é idêntico ao seu código [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), ou seja, o caractere `'0'` será considerado igual ao inteiro `48` (`30` em hexadecimal), o caractere `'1'` ao `49`, etc.

   No início do seu programa você definiu constantes (`domingo`, `segunda`, etc) para armazenar o código de cada dia. Por que não usá-los então, em vez de repetir o número no código?

   ```
   if ( ch == domingo ) {
   ```

   E quando não tem código, compare sempre caractere com caractere, é mais garantido:

   ```
   else if (ch>'7' && ch!='0'){
   ```

   (embora nesse último caso, seria melhor fazer só um `else` - sem `if` - pois pode acontecer também do caractere ser **menor** do que `'0'`: por exemplo `'+'`, `'-'`, `'!'`...)
3. Você só lê um caractere do teclado uma única vez, depois disso entra no laço `while`. Nesse laço você testa o caractere, faz alguma coisa, depois usa `break`. Isso faz com que você saia do laço, o que não é bem o que você quer (a menos que a opção escolhida seja o `0`). É preciso retirar esses `break`s, mas antes acrescente uma linha no final do `while` para ler um *novo* caractere do teclado (se você não fizer isso, o valor de `ch` nunca vai mudar e seu programa vai entrar num *loop* infinito).

   ```
   while ( ch != '0' ) {
       if ( ch == domingo ) {
           printf(" domingo  \n");
           // break;
       } 
       else if ( ch == segunda ) {
           printf(" segunda \n");
           // break;
       }
       ...
       else {
           printf(" numero de dia nao valido \n");
           // break;     
       }
       ch = getchar(); // Lê outro caractere do teclado
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

@mgibsonbr já disse tudo. O código abaixo serve apenas para salientar
a importância (discutível) das simetrias verticais na indentação do código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define clearbuff     while(getchar()!='\n');

int main(void){
  int ch;
  printf("digite um numero que corresponde a um dia da semana: \n");

  while((ch=getchar()-'0') != 0){
         if (ch==1){ printf(" domingo\n"); }
    else if (ch==2){ printf(" segunda\n"); }
    else if (ch==3){ printf(" terca\n")  ; }
    else if (ch==4){ printf(" quarta\n") ; }   
    else if (ch==5){ printf(" quinta\n") ; }
    else if (ch==6){ printf(" sexta\n")  ; }
    else if (ch==7){ printf(" sabado\n") ; }
    else           { printf(" numero de dia nao valido\n"); }

    clearbuff;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Tive ainda de mudar os "conio.h" (que é dependente de plataforma, não existe tal coisa no C do meu linux)